# How to Convert ObservableCollection to MyCollection:ObservableCollection<MyClass>

Tags: c#, linq, casting, observablecollection

I have a Custom Observable Collection of MyClass

```
 class MyClass
    {
    }

 class MyObservablECollection : ObservableCollection<MyClass>
    {
    }
```

Now I am creating objects of them both :

```
 ObservableCollection<MyClass> _varObsCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

 MyObservablECollection _varMyObservablECollection = new MyObservablECollection();

_varMyObservablECollection = _varObsCollection;

var _obsvleCollection  = new  ObservableCollection<MyCollection>(_myVar);

MyCollection _tempCollection = new  ObservableCollection<MyCollection>(_myVar);
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' to 'MyObservablECollection'

I know that we cannot assign parent class object (`ObservableCollection<MyClass>`) to child class `MyObservablECollection`

But is there a way I can cast them?

Comment: In general if you want to do something like this you create a constructor for `MyObservableCollection` that takes the `ObservableCollection` as a paremeter and then constructs the object you want. There is no concept of casting in this direction simply because you need to create information out of nowhere (eg all the extra stuff that might be on your subtype) - this is why you need explicit code to do it. You probably could do it by adding casting operators onto your class but I'd personally go for the constructor approach.

Answer (score -1):

You got it upside down, this is the working case:

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> _tempCollection = new MyCollection(_myVar);
```

`MyCollection` is `ObservableCollection<MyCollection>` but `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` is not necessarily `MyCollection`.

Edit: I understand you were trying to maintain that same order.
In that case - not possible due to how inheritance work.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that parent can not be assigned to child, but if there is a way

Comment: That would work but is not what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Simsons Could you expand on why you want `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` instance to be set on `MyCollection` var?